# How to play audio on python without saving an audio file

Tags: machine-learning, audio, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am working with Tensorflow_TTS. I am generating audio using fastspeech and melgan. Now this audio is an eager tensor, more precisely: `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>` . I want to play this audio tensor in the script without converting it to an audio file and then playing it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you working in a jupyter environment?

Comment: No its a python script, doesnt matter I just figured it out, thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Noob that I am I just figured it out, using the sounddevice library in python I was able to play the audio without saving it by converting the eagertensor to a numpy array.